# Django expression DateTime and Integer seconds

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to annotate the difference between a DateTime and an Integer (seconds) on a legacy MySQL DB (so there is no chance to change the IntegerField to a DurationField) with Django 1.11

```
Report(Model):
    # time the report was sent
    time = DateTimeField()
    # seconds since the last reboot
    uptime = IntegerField()

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    last_report=Max(time),
    last_reboot=ExpressionWrapper(F('last_report') - F('uptime')), output_field=DateTimeField())
)
```

This would work, if `uptime` was a DurationField(), but won't work with an integer. So I tried converting the seconds to a timedelta

```
last_reboot=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('last_report') - F(timezone.timedelta(seconds=1)*F('uptime')),
    output_field=DateTimeField()
)
```

which gives me

> AttributeError at ...
>
> 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'split'

Is there a way to calculate with a DateTimeField() and a IntegerField() in a query expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution: Convert the integer to a duration using the `ExpressionWrapper`. As I am getting seconds and a `DurationField()` is Microseconds, I have to multiply them by 1,000,000.

```
last_reboot=ExpressionWrapper(
    F('last_report') - ExpressionWrapper(
        F('uptime') * 1000000,
        output_field=DurationField()
    ),
    output_field=DateTimeField()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Previously, I did something like below...might be useful for others.

```
.annotate(timestamp=RawSQL('DATE(milisecond_datetimestamp, \'unixepoch\')',[]))
```

and another query where I had to convert the date integer field to hour

```
.annotate(hour=Round(F('milisecond_datetimestamp') % (3600 * 24) /3600))
```

and for `Round` you have to define SQL function like below

```
class Round(Func):
    function= 'ROUND'
```

Comment: I try to avoid `RawSQL` and `extra()`. But the `Round` approach is not bad. I'll still go with the `ExpressionWrapper`. But thanks!